# Why isn’t “him that is” instead “him who is” in this passage from the 1500s?

Tags: grammar, legalese, who-that

From page 123 of Frederick Schauer’s *Thinking Like a Lawyer*:

> As long ago as the sixteenth century, Lord Selden observed that
>
> > . . . Equity is
> >     according to the conscience of him **that** is Chancellor, and as that is
> >     longer or narrower so is equity. ’Tis all one as if they should make the
> >     standard for the measure [of a linear foot] a Chancellor’s foot.

I realise that this is from the 16<sup>th</sup> century, but shouldn’t the bold *that* be *who* there?

I wouldn’t expect someone as learned as Lord Selden to err grammatically like this.

Comment: Today, this usage would be regarded as old-fashioned -- archaic, even -- but it is/was not incorrect in terms of the English spoken back in Lord Selden's day. You should be careful about applying contemporary standards of English to the English spoken in earlier decades or centuries. You need only go back to the English of the early 20th century to encounter some constructions that already sound odd today.

Comment: '... of him who is ...' may be grammatical, but that's the only good thing you can say about it.

Comment: [He **that** hath an ear, let him hear what the Spirit saith unto the churches](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+2%3A17&version=KJV). This looks to me like an ill-targeted peeve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is perhaps more interesting historically than the OP realizes because it involves warring prescriptivists—on the one side those who argue that a person should always be connected to a following clause by *who*, and on the other those that argue that the choice between *that* and *who* should follow the same logic as the choice between *that* and *which*.

The OP's surprise at the occurrence of *that* in the cited excerpt indicates that he or she aligns with the first group of prescriptivists. Andrea Lunsford, *The St Martin's Handbook*, Fifth Edition (2003) lays out a somewhat qualified version of their position:

> **that, which, who** Use *that* when referring to things or to a group of people. *A band **that** tours frequently will please its fans.* Use *which* only when referring to things. *The new album, **which** is the band's first in years, appeals to new listeners.* Use *who* to refer to people. *Alex is the band member **who** plays drums.* In conversation, *that* can be used to refer to an individual (*the man **that** plays drums*), but in academic and professional writing, use *who* (*the man **who** plays drums*).

Frank Vizetelly, *A Desk Book of Errors in English*, Second Edition (1920) speaks for a different group of prescriptivists:

> **that, who :** Discriminate carefully between these words. *That* implies restriction; *who* generally denotes coordination. As an illustration of this distinction, Alfred Ayres says [citation omitted] " 'I met the boatman *who* took me across the ferry.' If *who* is the proper word here, the meaning is 'I met the boatman, and he took me across the ferry,' it being supposed that the boatman is known and definite. But if there be several boatmen, and I wish to indicate one in particular, by the circumstance that he had taken me across the ferry, I should use *that*." *That* ought, therefore, to be preferred to *who* or *which* whenever an antecedent not otherwise limited is to be restricted by the relative clause.

Both of these prescriptions have problems, however. In his coverage of *that* vs. *who*, Wilson Follett, *Modern American Usage* (1966) notes the ahistoricism of the Lunsford position:

> Historically there is not much ground for objecting to *that* as a personal relative pronoun. *He that hath clean hands* / *the world and they that dwell therein* / *He that is most knowing hath the capacity to become happy* / *They that on glorious ancestors enlarge* / *vile man that mourns* / *thou that listenest to sighs of orphans* / *I am he that walks* / *children that belonged to a man I didn't even know* / *An optimist is a guy that has never had much experience*. Such a scattering, which happens to reach from from the King James translation of the Old Testament to Whitman, Mark Twain, and Don Marquis, could be extended to prove that the relative *that* refers to persons quite as naturally as to things, and quite as naturally as *who* refers to things. ... It often happens that *that* is obligatory and *who* is impossible; for example in Marlowe's line *Who ever loved that loved not at first sight?* it would be distracting to pile a relative *who* on the opening interrogative *Who*. We are, then, free to use *that* instead of *who* for a sign of the restrictive clause about persons, exactly as many elect to use it instead of *which* in a restrictive clause about things—and for similar reasons.

On the other hand, Follett recognizes that *who* doesn't work on the ear as if it were simply the person-focused correlative of *which* for things:

> But a great many of these same writers [who consistently use *that* in place of *which* as the characteristic pronoun of the restrictive or defining clause] do not feel comfortable with *that* as the signal of the restrictive clause about persons, for which they retain the *who* of the nonrestrictives. Kipling, for example, seems not to mind whatever appearance of inconsistency there may be in shifting from *The Light That Failed* to *The Man Who Would Be King* and *The Man Who Was*. As a matter of fact, the dislike of *that* applied to persons is not to be written off as a mere caprice. It is a usage that unquestionably leads into more frequent and more extreme awkwardness than we can charge to the same *that* applied to things. Any writer or editor has to wriggle through a variety of such snarls as *fully persuaded that children that undergo the handicap of teachers that have only a perfunctory grasp of these fundamentals are to be pitied*; and it will not take many of them to persuade him that the substitution of *who* has its advantages.

Having considered the difficulties inherent in both prescriptions, Follett offers a modest recommendation:

> [S]hift freely between *that* and *who* in personal restrictive clauses, according to which produces the greater ease and naturalness in the sentence.

In other words, trust your own ears.

Comment: How can a non-native-speaker learner of English trust their own ears?

Comment: I don't think that they safely can. I think Follett intends his advice for more-advanced English speakers and writers.